# Failure on setting Person/Group column via SPD

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a SharePoint Online site where I am trying to set a person/group column via a SharePoint Designer workflow.  The Library where I am trying to set the column has major versioning enabled and requires approval but does not require check-in/check-out (Although I have tried check-out from within the workflow before changing the column and check-in at the end of the workflow).  I have tried to set the value of the column with both people and groups to no avail.  The column is set to allow both people and groups.  From within the workflow, I have used 'People/Groups from SharePoint site' and by selecting a group from 'Select from existing Users and Groups'.  To rule out anything else causing the issue, I reduced the workflow to include only setting the value of the column.  The error that I get is `Failed on Start` and the description of the error is `The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information.`  Any ideas?

Comment: When you select the the person or group field in the workflow, make sure you set the value to Display Name.

Comment: I am setting a value, not getting a value.  Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, this issue only occurred on a site column that was bound to the site content type present in the list.  When I added a column directly to the list, I could populate the item via SharePoint Designer Workflow as expected.

EDIT: Not exactly.  Although I can repeat the issue, I could not repeat the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try the link below...........
*https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uksharepoint/2009/02/17/quick-tip-using-the-sharepoint-person-or-group-field-in-code/*

Comment: Instead of providing a link to a possible solution hosted on an external website, please provide the answer or its key point(s) here by having the reference URL mentioned. This way we can prevent a situation where the link to an external source would one day break, and the solution would become inaccessible.